# print button on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

is there a simple way to put a print button on an asp.net page which, instead of printing the entire page, will print only a couple of fields?

Answer (score 9):

It what you want is this to be the case whenever the page prints, you could add another stylesheet with a media="print" attribute and in that stylesheet, hide every field apart from the two you care about.